# Neural network, what is the error value for a layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I am new to neural networks. I am studying back propagation and saw different references. for a layer $k$, some references state that the error $\delta_j^k$ for neuron $j$ at $k$th layer is

$$
\delta_j^k = \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial a_j^k}
$$

while some other references state

$$
\delta_j^k = \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial z_j^k}
$$
where $z^k = w^l a^{(l-1)} + b^k$. Andrew Ng in his courses introduced this as
$$
\delta^k = (W^{(k+1)})^T \delta^{(k+1)} .* \sigma^{'}(z^{(k)})
$$
that made me confused. Which one is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question very much depends on the resource that you are using (i.e. there is no real right or wrong).

When using the notation $\boldsymbol{z}^{(l)} = \boldsymbol{W}^{(l)} \boldsymbol{a}^{(l-1)} + \boldsymbol{b}^{(l)}$ and $\boldsymbol{a}^{(l)} = \phi\bigl(\boldsymbol{z}^{(l)}\bigr)$, the error given by $$\boldsymbol{\delta}^{(l)} = {\boldsymbol{W}^{(l+1)}}^\mathsf{T} \boldsymbol{\delta}^{(l+1)} \odot \phi'\bigl(\boldsymbol{z}^{(l)}\bigr)$$
is the derivative w.r.t. the pre-activations, i.e. $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \boldsymbol{z}^{(l)}}$.
(Note: I took the liberty to use $\phi$ for the activation function and $\odot$ to denote the Hadamard (i.e. element-wise) product.)

When considering the gradient w.r.t. the activations, i.e. $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \boldsymbol{a}^{(l)}}$, the error would be $$\boldsymbol{d}^{(l)} = {\boldsymbol{W}^{(l)}}^\mathsf{T} \boldsymbol{d}^{(l+1)} \odot \phi'\bigl(\boldsymbol{z}^{(l)}\bigr).$$
The difference is subtle, but the recursion aligns the weights differently.

However, you will rarely find the latter expression, because (almost) everyone uses the gradients w.r.t. the pre-activations.
For some intuition as to why that is, I refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/259323/95000) I gave to another question.